# Using commas after clause starting with 'not'

Tags: grammar, commas, clauses

I have the following sentence:

```
He wanted to go to the park, not the city, for lunch
```

Is the second comma needed?

Comment: Yes, "not the city" is a parenthetical clause.  It either gets a comma on both ends or none at all.  (I'd advise using the commas in this case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave out the comma the sentence has a different meaning.

*"He wanted to go to the park, not the city for lunch"* means that the choices are (a) go to the park and (b) go to the city for lunch. Lunch in the park is not implied.

*"He wanted to go to the park, not the city, for lunch"* means that the choices are (a) go to the park for lunch and (b) go to the city for lunch. Lunch happens in both places.

Comment: @MikeG Firstly, you mean "For instance:" (not "For instants:"). Secondly, with adjectives it *can* still work, but you need to drop the second 'a', like this: "It was a cute, not beautiful, dog.". However, it does seem a bit clunky, so "It was a cute dog, [but] not a beautiful one." (optional 'but') works better.